# Bash script variables not set in CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos, centos7

Consider the following code (script file):

```sh
someVar=null

doSomething() {
   someVar='test'
}

printSomething() {
   echo $someVar;
}

doSomething
printSomething
```

In **Ubuntu** (distro 18.04), the code prints `test`. However, in **CentOS** (distro 7.6), the code prints `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Okay, my actual code is a little bit different.  So, the above actually does run on CentOS.  However, the below does not (prints null):

```sh
someVar=null

checkSomething() {
   someVar='test'

   return 0
}

printSomething() {
   echo $someVar;
}

if (checkSomething -eq 0) 
then
   printSomething
fi
```

It may have to do with process or something, but trying to write a function that sets the global variable and returns `0` for success (or `1` if failure)

Comment: (Mind you, there's good reason to consider global variables by default bad design; but it's a bad design decision that was codified into the POSIX sh specification in the early 90s, so anyone who claims to make a POSIX-family shell and doesn't behave thusly is making a false claim).

Comment: `bash`, `Linux centos-jd 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.  This is on OpenLogic's CentOS 7.6

Comment: Another useful thing to add would be the trace logs emitted by `bash -x yourscript` in the CentOS case.

Comment: bash version: `4.2.46(2)-release`

Comment: check the edit, please

Comment: That's not "a little" different. `(checkSomething -eq 0)` doesn't perform any comparisons; it calls `checkSomething` with two arguments (`-eq` and `0`) that it ignores. Critically, it does so in a *subshell*, so the change to `someVar` only exists in that subshell.

Comment: Which is to say, it's identical to `if checkSomething; then printSomething; fi`, *except* for the subshell throwing away side effects (like your variable assignment), and making things slower.

Comment: Moreover -- that code **can't possibly work in Ubuntu either.**

Comment: re: Ubuntu, I added the `if` after I copied the code from Ubuntu to CentOS. So it may not.  Bottom line is...how do I accomplish my task?

Comment: `if checkSomething; then printSomething; fi`.

Comment: thank you for your help!